# pointer alignment right for variables, and left for functions

Tags: c, clang-format

If I use this option in clang-format configuration:

```
PointerAlignment: Right
```

the star would be attached to variable's name. For example:

```
char *p;
```

If I try this option on a function, it will produce this:

```
char *foo(void);
```

So, is there an option to make it left alignment for function? I would like to get this:

```
char* foo(void);
```

Comment: Attaching the `*` to the function name is consistent with `char *p;`, why do you want to use a different convention for functions?  The convention used in the C Standard is to attach the `*` to the function name, eg: `char *strchr(const char *s, int c);`

Comment: You will need to rewrite all standard headers

Comment: "Misra defines that when defining pointer types, the star should be attached to the variable's name. " No it doesn't, where did you hear that? MISRA C is explicitly not a style guide and any rules you may find in it are only concerned with safety. Such as for example never writing selection/iteration statements without `{ }` - it has been found that code which isn't using `{ }` is much more bug-prone, hence the MISRA rule.

Comment: *Misra defines that when defining pointer types, the star should be attached to the variable's name.* -- MISRA makes no such assertion.

Comment: @Andrew you are right. I was quickly going through misra 2004 and our coding style documents and must have mixed things up. Fixed it in the last edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C declaration syntax works around an identifier which has some operators applied to it, in a certain precedence. The list of type specifiers specify the type of the expression after all these operators are applied. Functions are not a special case in that regard. In fact, you can have the following forward declaration:

```
int f(void), *g(void);
```

This means that the expressions `f()` and `*g()` both yield an `int`. Applying the function-call operator on `f` yields an `int`. Applying the function-call operator on `g` and then the `*` unary operator also yields an `int`.

This is why the "natural" way of things is to put the asterisk next to the identifier.

Comment: Indeed - and ``int * i, j`` does not result in what many may expect...

Comment: what made me accept your answer are actually comments under my question about standard headers